# How do I create an if condition using calculated columns in a single table?

Tags: sql, date

My table contains a column called `BATCH_DATE`, and a calculated column that returns the MIN of BATCH_DATE, called `MIN_BATCH_DATE`.

I need a new column `CHECK` that gets a value of A1 when the `BATCH_DATE` is the same as `MIN_BATCH_DATE`, otherwise give it a value of B1.

I was wondering what the best way to tackle this would be?

I want something like this

```
[BATCH_DATE]  [BATCH_DATE_MIN]   [CHECK]

 2007-05-01    2007-05-01         A1
 2007-05-01    2007-02-01         B1
```

Comment: Add some sample table data, and the expected result. (As well formatted text, mark and click `{}`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN BATCH_DATE = MIN_BATCH_DATE THEN 'A1'
             ELSE 'B1'
        END)CHECK_DT
```